# Нужно написать тесты на rest application

Tags: javascript, yii, backbone.js, test-driven-development, jasmine

Разрабатываю небольшое приложение. За основу взял https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBackbone

Нужно написать функциональне тесты на REST и (опционально) юнит тесты. Не могу разобраться, вроде бы установлен jasmine, не пойму, как им пользоваться и где вообще искать тесты.

Если их нет, подскажите, где можно взять заготовки для BDD для REST full

Comment: Как там ваши успехи в решении задачи? Если решили, можете сами написать ответ, он будет полезен будущим читателям.

Comment: Готово.........

Answer (score 1):

Ответов не дождался. Решил задачу следующим образом. Установил плагин postman для chrome. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Плагин имеет возможность вручнуую тестировать АПИ, есть все виды http запросов. Так же позволяет авторизоваться и отправлять любой JSON в теле заголовка.

Более того, в плагине есть авто-тесты (коллекции). Это набор запросов, в которых можно через JavaScript писать сами проверки. Есть набор сниппетов, проверяющих структуру JSON или статус-код ответа. А вообще есть объект запроса и респонса, которые можно проверять в рамках запроса. Тесты запускаются и выдают наглядный результат.
Минусы - плагин платный. 10$ 
Очень удобный инструмент, рекомендую. Надеюсь, кому то поможет.

Comment: Postman очень удобная штука для ручного тестирования, но совсем не подходящая для автоматического тестирования. Я очень рекомендую изучить любой фреймворк, без этого прелести CI не откроются.

Comment: Под мои задачи идеально вписался. А так - я с Вами согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Для тестирования REST есть масса возможностей с использованием модулей для Node.js. Например http://frisbyjs.com/, если вы хотите пользоваться неким готовым фреймворком или например я предпочитаю использовать обычный https://github.com/request/request . Тесты с использованием этих инструментов пишутся на обычном Javascript.

Запуск тестов с отлично автоматизируются, их можно запускать с помощью Jenkins например.